# Printing to Star TSP143LAN from NodeJS on Linux, with formatting

Tags: node.js, linux, printing

I have the proper CUPS drivers installed: I can print to my Star TSP143LAN using any application with print capability (like Chrome). I can print to this printer using the node-printer module, by specifying either the printer name or the printer’s network address, and setting the print mode to TEXT.

But I can’t seem to format what I print from NodeJS using the node-printer library. If I set the mode to RAW and send commands as specified in Star’s Command Line Emulator manual for this printer, node-printer will report a successful print but nothing happens. It doesn’t print.

I’m attempting to send these RAW commands because I want to do various formatting operations like make the font larger or bold, and so on.

I’ve tried the node-thermal-printer module but I’ve had no luck.

I’ve been scouring the internet for some help on this issue but I haven’t been able to find much. I’ve seen it mentioned that the TSP143 LAN doesn’t communicate in the same way as other star products and it’s best to use Star’s drivers as a go-between, but I’m not sure what that means. (I thought I might be doing that already when specifying the printer’s class name when attempting to print from node-printer...)

I didn’t have much trouble implementing the Star Swift SDK into an iOS app and doing formatting operations there. But I need to print from a NodeJS environment on Linux. I’m at a loss.

If there’s anybody to whom this sounds familiar and can point me in the right direction I’d be very grateful...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, it looks like the Star TSP100/TSP143 LAN is not able to print using Line Mode Commands or ESC/POS from Linux: the solution has been to generate a PDF from HTML (using wkhtmltopdf) and then print the PDF using the node printer library (https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer). I have not yet found a better way to properly format prints.